# How to add a script task to run pytest in Bamboo

Tags: python, pytest, bamboo

I am setting up a build configuration using Bamboo and this is my first time with the tool. Code checkout and build step is done and now I'd like to add test step. I tried adding script

```
    python -m pytest tests/*
```

but I get

```
    /usr/bin/python: No module named pytest
```

What is the correct way of adding pytest step?

Answer (score 1):

Bamboo tasks run a different terminal environment than your local shell or cmd environment.   If you follow the logs you can see the exact environment variables that Bamboo has access to in the big blue block.  The easiest way to solve these kinds of errors is to set the PATH to whatever you are trying to use in the Environment Variables block:

```
PATH="$PATH:/path/to/python/modules"
```

If using pip you can get the path by doing the following:

```
pip install pytest
pip show pytest
```